# Hide all rows that do not match driverNo.Text

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I want to hide all rows in datagrid which do not match the text in **driverNo.Text**, but when **driverNo.Text** is null, I'd like all the rows in datagrid to appear. How would I accomplish this?

```
    private void driverNo_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == driverNo.Text)
            {

            }
            else if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == null)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A better way may be to filter the datasource. Is this a bound grid? If you bind to a DataView you can use its filter property. In the above you can set the row height to 0 but it won't disappear completely. e.g. row.Height = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve the problem:

```
CurrencyManager manager = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
manager.SuspendBinding();
bool shouldNotFilter = string.IsNullOrEmpty(driverNo.Text);
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (shouldNotFilter)
    {
        row.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!string.Equals(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), driverNo.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            row.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            row.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
manager.ResumeBinding();
```

This approach is straight forward but slow, I'd suggest you take a look at `DataView` and its `RowFilter` property. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2485839/2974754) is a good example.

Comment: Hi Yuriy - thanks for the help. I've tried the above code, and each time I type in any number greater than 1 it crashes my app with the error message: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll. Additional information: Row associated with the currency manager's position cannot be made invisible.`

Comment: @Antoine-LaurentLavoisier, I suspect you are using `CurrencyManager` in the following way `CurrencyManager manager = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[datagridview1.DataSource];
` you can add following lines before and after provided code `manager.SuspendBinding();`, `manager.ResumeBinding();` respectively. This should solve the problem, but it's not a good solution, I'd suggest taking a look at DataView. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please update the answer to reflect it - this is how my code looks like at the moment - http://pastebin.com/xNGgsdKi

Comment: Thanks Yuriy - quick question. It seems that the code stops searching through the rows whenever I press backspace, e.g. when I type in *12* and then backspace on the 2 and leave 1, then it doesn't pick up 1 anymore

Comment: @Antoine-LaurentLavoisier, `KeyUp` event is not raised for some of the keys, so you might hook up your logic to the `TextChanged` event instead.

Comment: Just have - still the same issue. I've typed in 50 and nothing appears, but when I backspace on the 0, leaving the 5, the row with the number 5 doesn't show

Comment: Yeah, there was an issue with the logic, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you need, but something along these lines?

```
private void driverNo_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Set all rows.Visible = false in design
    if (driverNo.Text = "")
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == driverNo.Text)
            {
                row.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will make all rows visible if the driverNo.Text is null and only show the rows with what is contained in driverNo.Text otherwise.

NOTE: The rows need to not be visible to start, or you can make them visible to start and just change the if statement to `!= driverNo.Text` and set to `false`

Comment: Suppose the rows are visible to start - would the code look like this? http://pastebin.com/e0attSHs